# Divs Overlapping on window resize

Tags: css, css-float, html

I got the following css:

```
#columnai {
  float:left;
  height: 100%;
  width:35%;
  left:0;
  position: fixed;  
  min-height:640px; 
  clear:right;
}

#columnad {
  float:right;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left:35%;
  width:65%;
}
```

i cant figure out how to make them not overlap on window resize, i put them inside a wrapper

```
#pagina {
  padding:0px;
  marging:0px;
  float:left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width:1000px;
}
```

being min-width the property that make them not overlap but clearly thats not a good fix, doesnt work when zooming in mobiles (i use mediaqueries to make #columnai not fixed)

Thanks

Comment: try posting some html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your html looks something similar to this:

```
<div id="pagina">
    <div id="columnai">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div id="columnad">
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm guessing you want your #columnai to be a fixed width and the #columnad to expand to the rest of the width. While tables are not semantic, using the display property in CSS is perfectly acceptable, as long as the elements have semantic meaning. Using your example:

```
#columnai {
  display:table-cell;
  width:200px;
}

#columnad {
  display:table-cell;
}

#pagina {
  display:table;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #columnai, #columnad {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 0 20px 0;
  }
}
```

The media query is just an example of how you would support a smaller/mobile browser.  In the working example, expand the window (or pane size) to see the switch between the media query and the larger format.  http://jsfiddle.net/zyglobe/YcFBX/

Comment: Thats exactly the behaviour im after, i added the display, removed any other property i had, however if i dont set a width to #columnad it completely overlaps columnai and takes the whole page for itself, i tried to add a third column in between but it overlaps columnai aswell